# How to change the color of one column in grid of Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am making a report in which I am grouping the Details section (grid) by a name field.  I used this formula to change the background color of every second row and that works too:

```
if Remainder(RecordNumber,2) = 0
then 
Color(203,211,241)
else
crNoColor
```

So, I have something like this:

```
GroupByName
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                Date                   ID                    TransactionsID
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              .........              .........                    .........     White Row
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I want white  .........              .........                    .........     Light Blue Row
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
              .........              .........                    .........     White Row
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I want white  .........              .........                    .........     Light Blue Row
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That formula does the trick for each row all the way. But, I want the first column to be white, because there is nothing inside and I will put some lines later. I hope someone had the same request and that can be practically solved.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a white-colored box to that portion of the Details section

Comment: I was going to write here a comment, I added a box filled it with white and set the border lines color to white too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a white-colored box with a white border to that portion of the Details section and extend it all the way to the top and bottom of the section (it may be helpful to right-click the box, select "Format Box", and then select "Extend to Bottom of Section when Printing") so that it appears seamless when the report is displayed.

Another possibly useful tidbit is that CR does not allow box objects to be placed *in front of* or overlayed on top of certain other objects, like database fields. So, if you need to white-out other objects on the report then it's better to use a text object without actually entering any text and just treating it as a box object (you can still give it a background color, border, etc.)